# How to say "Contains Nothing" in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to add the class "foo" to all span tags on a document that do not have any text inside them. How to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('span:empty').addClass('foo');
```

Just keep in mind that the [`empty-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) means absolutely empty, meaning no spaces.

If you want to allow for whitespace, do this:

```
$('span').filter(function() {
    return !$.trim( this.innerHTML );
}).addClass('foo');
```

This uses the [`jQuery.trim()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method inside the [`filter()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to allow for elements that have only whitespace content (with no elements).

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
$('span').each(function() { 
   if ($.trim($(this).text()).length == 0) { 
      $(this).addClass('foo');
   }
});
```